# Running cygwin chere in mintty

Tags: cygwin, mintty

Whenever I use `chere`'s "Bash Prompt Here", the bash prompt runs in Window's `cmd.exe`. Is there a way to have it directly run `mintty` in the directory, instead of just `cmd.exe` with bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently `chere` has an option to specify which terminal to use, with the -t option
For example, to use `mintty`, run

```
chere -i -t mintty
```

Answer (score 0):

make a new shortcut to mintty.exe and put

`C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -e /path/to/chere`

as target in it

an not sure what chere is, please give us a link..

Comment: chere is a package that you can get in cygwin that adds an option to run cygwin in a certain path with an entry in windows explorer's context menu